# mysql - query which provides additional column with iterative number by condition

Tags: mysql, query

I do have a table which looks like this. 
Already grouped by user_id AND activity date:

```
[user_id] [activity_date]
123455     '2019-07-01'
123455     '2019-07-02'
123455     '2019-07-03'
222222     '2019-07-01'
222222     '2019-07-02'
```

Is it possible to write a query which gives me an additional column like this:

```
 [user_id] [activity_date]   [additional_counter]
123455     '2019-07-01'        1
123455     '2019-07-02'        2
123455     '2019-07-03'        3
222222     '2019-07-01'        1
222222     '2019-07-02'        2
```

It should just count up if the user_id has the same predecessor (same user_id).

Comment: Have you tried writing the query? Also, this is mostly a programming question (for Stack Overflow) rather than an administration one (DBA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL 8+

```
SELECT user_id, activity_date, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY activity_date ASC) additional_counter
FROM tablename;
```

For MySQL 5+

```
SELECT t1.user_id, t1.activity_date, COUNT(t2.activity_date) additional_counter
FROM tablename t1, tablename t2
WHERE t1.activity_date >= t2.activity_date
  AND t1.user_id = t2.user_id
GROUP BY t1.user_id, t1.activity_date;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3648d535fb827f3c5a290ddee6141405)

Comment: Thank you! This solution worked for me!